# Two different AJAX forms not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

Hello I'm working on rails and have been trying to make ajax requests when submiting forms for comments so the result is appended to the list of comments. I've got it to work thanks to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-sns5tNdTY .

Later I decided to add answers to my comments, which I implemented with a new model and made a coffeescript on each comment to show me the answers and a form to answer to that specific comment. It was kind of a pain in the ass but got it to work finally.

Now I've got my answers working just fine, but the comment form is not working through AJAX, the comments are getting posted, but not appended to the comment list.

What I get is a console error when inspecting on chrome:

jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:10255 POST http://localhost:3000/comentarios 500 (Internal Server Error)

This is how I render the comments and the form (sorry for it being in spanish):

```
<div id="seccion-comentarios" class="border-element-sm-div" style="overflow: hidden">
                    <h3 style="width: 500px">Comentarios</h3>
                        <div id="comentarios">
                            <%= render @comentarios %>
                        </div>
                    <% if @comentarios.count <= 0 %>
                        <p style="font-style: italic; color: grey; margin-left: 10px"> Aún no hay comentarios. Haz uno!</p>
                    <% end %>
                    <% if usuario_signed_in? %>
                    <div style="overflow: auto">
                        <%= render :partial => 'comentarios/form' %>
                    </div>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
```

This is the form for my comments (views/comentarios/form):

```
<%= form_for @comentario , remote: true do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :favor_id, value: @favor.id%>

            <%= f.label :texto, "Escribe un comentario:" %>
            <br/>
            <%= f.text_area :texto, required: true,class: "form-control", style: "width: 99%; max-width: 99%"%>

        <div style="float: right; padding-top: 10px; margin-right: 1%">
            <%= f.submit "Comentar", :class=>'btn btn-primary'%>
        </div>

<% end %>
```

And this is the create.js.erb for that inside views/comentarios

```
$('#comentarios').append($("<%= j render @comentario %>").hide().fadeIn(500));
$('#comentario_texto').val("");
```

Then for each comment I render this:

```
            <div class="border-gau-sm" style="overflow: auto">
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td height="60" style="min-width: 60px; vertical-align: top">
                            <div class="image-container-nav">
                                <% if Usuario.find(comentario.usuario_id).foto.presence %>
                                <%= image_tag Usuario.find(comentario.usuario_id).foto, title:"FotoUsuario", class:"img-sm"%>
                                <% else %>
                                <%= image_tag "foto_stock.png", title:"FotoUsuario", class:"img-sm"%>
                                <% end %>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>                
                            <div style="margin-left: 5px;">
                                <p style="font-size: 16px"><b><%= link_to Usuario.find(comentario.usuario_id).nombre.capitalize+" "+Usuario.find(comentario.usuario_id).apellido.capitalize, usuario_path(:id => comentario.usuario_id)%></b></p>
                                <p style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: -15px; font-style: italic; color: grey"> <%= comentario.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") %> </p>
                                <p style="margin-top: -10px"><%= comentario.texto%></p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div style="float: right; margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: -2px;">
                    <% if (current_usuario.id == comentario.usuario_id)%>
                    <%= link_to "Eliminar", comentario, method: :delete, data: {confirm: '¿Esta seguro de eliminar este comentario?'}, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs' %>
                    <% end%>

                    <a class= "respuestas-link btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-section-id="respuestas-seccion-<%=comentario.id%>" href="#">
                        Respuestas
                        <span class="caret" style=""></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <section id="respuestas-seccion-<%=comentario.id%>" style="display: none">
                    <br/>
                    <div>
                        <div id="seccion-respuestas" style="overflow: auto">
                            <% respuestas = comentario.answers %>
                            <div id="respuestas-<%=comentario.id%>">
                                <%= render respuestas %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="overflow: auto">
                            <%= render :partial => 'answers/form', :locals => {:coment => comentario}  %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
```

where I render each answer and this form for each comment:

```
<%= form_for @respuesta , remote: true do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :comentario_id, value: coment.id%>
            <%= f.label :texto, "Escribe una respuesta:" %>
            <br/>
            <textarea required="required" class="form-control" style="width: 99%; max-width: 99%" name="answer[texto]" id="answer_texto_<%=coment.id%>"></textarea>

        <div style="float: right; padding-top: 10px; margin-right: 1%">
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
        </div>

<% end %>
```

And get it working through ajax through this create.js.erb in /views/answers/create.js.erb

```
$('#respuestas-' + <%= @respuesta.comentario.id %>).append($("<%= j render @respuesta %>").hide().fadeIn(500));
$('#answer_texto_' + <%= @respuesta.comentario.id %>).val("");
```

Finally I would like to say that I've tried removing the
`<%= render :partial => 'answers/form', :locals => {:coment => comentario}  %>` line in views/comentarios/_comentario.html.erb and the comment form  works just fine. 
I find it weird as there are many forms for answers in the page and all of them are working simultaneously without interfering with each other, except for the comments form.
Thanks for your time and hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out by inspecting with chrome in Network, XHR where I had a better explanation of the error:

ArgumentError in Comentarios#create

> Showing /app/views/answers/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised: First
>   argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

It was messing up with the @respuesta I used for other forms, so I added a @respuesta.new somewhere in the controller for Comentarios and that did the trick!